# Generators of $1+\Delta (G)$, where $\Delta(G)$ is augmentation ideal of group ring $FG.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, group-rings

Let $FG$  be a finite group ring  of a finite non abelian $p$-group $G$ over finite  field $F.$ It is well known that augmentation ideal $\Delta(G)=J(FG)$ has basis as the set $\{g-1:g\in G, g\ne 1\}$, being kernel of the augmentation map $f:FG\rightarrow F.$ Now my question is what is a generating set of $1+\Delta(G)?$  Can i say that its generating set is the set  $\{g\in G:g\ne 1\}?$

My real question is that as  i proved that $1+\Delta(G)$ is a finite non-abelian group. Can i say that exponent of this group will not exceed exponent of the group $G?$ Is there any way to find cardinality of $1+\Delta(G)?$  Please help me . Thanks .

Comment: **the** generating set? I think you must just mean **a** generating set.  The set you gave clearly does not generate it: every finite product of elements and their inverses in $G\setminus\{1\}$ is again an element of $G$, so you will never be able to generate $1+g_1-g_2 =1+(g_1-1)-(g_2-1)\in 1+\Delta(G)$ .  It can't generate any more than $G$, which is only a small portion of $1+\Delta(G)$. Are you under the misapprehension $1+\Delta(G)$ is closed under more operations than $\cdot$?

Comment: I've never really heard a proof that $1+\Delta(G)$ is a group.  It's obvious when $\Delta(G)$ is nilpotent... but otherwise what do you do? I know that the search for units in group rings is a deep subject, so if this is a standard result I'd appreciate a pointer.

Comment: @rschwieb $1+J[GF]$ is a normal subgroup of unit group $U(FG)$ of group ring $RG$

Comment: and in case of $p$-group Jacobson radical is same as Augmentation ideal i.e. $\Delta(G).$

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry for my poor english...

Comment: actually i am writing a research paper... there i got many problems... This site is only my guide ...

Comment: I am working to find unit group ....

Comment: The second thing you said (when $G$ is a $p$-group) would fall into the case of a nil $J(FG)=\Delta(G)$.  It's obvious that $1+J(FG)$ is a group, but it's not obvious that $1+\Delta(G)$ is often a group. Are you saying you've assumed $G$ is a $p$-group without saying so?

Comment: Yes in case of finite non-abelian $p$-group ....

Comment: "I am writing a research paper...This site is only my guide" You don't have an adviser, teacher or math department?

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: No adviser.........

Comment: I teaches and self study ....

Comment: @rschwieb   $$\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{F}G)\cong (1+J(\mathbb{F}G))\rtimes\mathcal{U}(\frac{\mathbb{F}G}{J(\mathbb{F}G)})$$

Comment: So i want to find order of $1+J(FG)$ ...and its exponent ....This my main question....